Difference between Birkas haMazon and Amidah with the Sequence of Blessings
When we say Birkas haMazon (blessing after meals), the second blessing contains thanksgiving Node L'kha with the addition for Chanukah and Purim and the third blessing of Yerushalaim contains request for Avodah/Service in the Temple with addition of Ya'aleh v'Yavo on Rosh Chodesh and Moadim.
In the last 3 blessings of Amidah the order is reversed. We first request for Avodah in the Temple with addition of Ya'aleh v'Yavo on Rosh Chodesh and Moadim. Afterwards we say thanksgiving Modim with the addition for Chanukah and Purim.
What is the reason for such a reversed order?

"When you have eaten your fill, you shall bless Hashem your God for the good land that He has given you." ((Deut.) Devarim 8:10)
The Talmud (Brachos 48b), explains that this mitzvah of blessing G-d after a meal (based on bread), is made of 4 blessings according to Jewish Law, and evolution. The first three blessings are directly relevant to the OP.
The first blessing of "Zan", was authored by Moshe Rabeinu in his times thanking G-d for the sustenance (as Moshe merited to receive the "Manna" from heaven which we ate for forty years).
The second blessing for "the Land of Israel", is attributed to Yehoshua bin Nun. He lead us in conquering Cana'an. By the time this blessing was enacted it marked the fact that Jews could finally fulfill the mitzvah of blessing after a meal for the first time in history as commanded. (The verse commanding blessing conditions the act of blessing on thanks for the Land.)
So once we miraculously received the land the second blessing is made for thanks and praise. Other things are then listed like Bris Milah, and Torah, and going out of Egyptian bondage. (without which nothing else was possible)
(The first blessing thanking for the miracle of Manna, would not have been appropriate to use to include references to thanks for the other items as we didn't have a land then; and Sichon and Og's lands didn't count as long as other Jews didn't have their land. Meanwhile since the Land is so significant, it rated its own seperate blessing. Once that happened, it became the blessing to list other items of thanks.)
So naturally, "Al HaNissim" for Channukah and Purim attaches to the second blessing for thanksgiving on the land and other miracles.
The third blessing is attributed to King David and King Solomon. In their time it was a pettition to build and establish Jerusalem and the Temple (and was so worded).
Nowadays we say it as a pettition to rebuild Jerusalem and the temple.
Therefore mentioning things which are connected with the missing Temple service are attached to this blessing.
This includes "R'tzey" and "Yaaleh v'Yavo" for the Sabbath, Rosh Chodesh, and the Festivals which have Biblically mandated "Korbanos" (temple offerings), while Purim and Channukah have no such mandate in the Torah.
Finally, the fourth blessing was instituted by The Sages of Yavneh during Roman occupation, for thanking G-d that the slain Jews of the city of Beytar miraculously did not decompose and were finally allowed burial by the Romans.
This thanks deserved its own special Rabbinical blessing which would not have normally been listed in the second blessing of thanks since that blessing focuses on miracles like the land which are Biblical pre-requisites for living people to fully take part in mitzvos. (Bris, Land, freedom, Torah)
Therefore kindness to the dead was viewed as a special seperate blessing.
On the  other hand.....
The Amidah prayer was compiled/formulated/standardized by The Men of the Great Assembly.(except for blessing 19 against heretics authored later in Roman times)
The blessing for the temple service follows immediately after a series of supplication requests ending in a request to ask G-d to return to Jerusalem and to return the Davidic dynasty. (followed by a general blessing for all possible requests)
The next blessing declares the return of the Temple Service which is the Biblical basis for pristine and organized prayers in the first place. So this follows in the previous order.
Since it addresses the Temple service itself, it is now appropriate to attach "Yaaleh v'Yavo" for Rosh Chodesh, and the Festivals which have Biblically mandated "Korbanos" (temple offerings), while Purim and Channukah (Al HaNissim), have no such mandate in the Torah.
The next blessing of thanksgiving (even if it might not be a "request") now includes thanks for everything from G-d, and for miracles such as those surrounding the holidays of Channukah and Purim; so "Al HaNissim" belongs here.
(Finally we beseech for Peace at the end of the Amidah because the Talmud explains Peace is the proper vessel by which all other blessing can be established properly so it must go at the end.)
So once you compare the way the blessing after a meal conforms with the verse commanding it and the evolution of Jewish history, and then realize how and why the Amidah prayer was formulated, the apparent contradictions or differences simply disappear.

Thank you for your attempt. You are writing a commentary on blessings, which we all know. The question is simpler. Could you please explain why the inyan of Avoda added by David and Shlomo should follow the inyan of Thanking added by Yehoshua. Why Yehoshua added inyan of Thanking, not Avodah. Also what makes the Amida different? Please add sources to justify.

I did not rate your answer yet.

Your questions in the comments were actually answered in my opinion. Maybe I write in a complicated manner. First, the assumption that there is an argument about a preferred order in mentioning thanks or avodah first and second, is a false assumption. Once you get that, the rest is easy. I showed why there is no connection between Bentching's order and the Amida's order regarding if thanks or avodah goes first. If you study the history and purpose of the two prayers, you will see why they are not comparative at all.

Specifically, Moshe only had Manna (sustenance), and no Land (main miracle of thanks) and no avodah (as his Mishkan was temporary and portable and was not established in the Land as Deut. mandates) Yehoshua had food and conquered much of the Land of E"Y. Now he could thank for the Land as the verse requires. But his avodah was in the Mishkan and not established yet, just like Moshe. Some of the Land was not yet conquered and no King and no war vs Amalek = so no Jerusalem/avodah. King David and King Solomon were told to make effort to buy and build Jerusalem after King Saul's war v. Amalek.

Why is the Amidah different?? Answer: Its not. and needs no justification as there is no comparrison or preffered order. Bentching needed its specific evolution. The Amidah was established all at once way after Bentching was completed. It has no rules of evolution. That's why it cannot be compared to bentching. The Sages simply set up the 18-19 blessings for various reasons, but that's not to do with your OP. Maybe you can help improve how I write if you agree to my premise.

I think this answers the question properly, in the sense that the order of the thanks evolved as a matter of historical additions, and this explains the time order of the additions and thus the reason for the different orders in the two liturgical contexts.

TY Mark Fischler

The OP makes the observation that while the Blessing after Meals has thanks first and mention of the Temple Service second, the Amidah prayer mentions the Temple Service first and thanks second. The OP then demands to know the significance behind this difference.
The answer is that there is no significance as the two prayers are not comparative at all.
(If the mere initial observation of such a "difference in order" has deeper meaning, then the burden of proof is on the OP to show why.)
Blessing after the Meal is based on a requirement found in the verse:
"When you have eaten your fill, you shall bless Hashem your God for the good land that He has given you." ((Deut.) Devarim 8:10)
The Talmud (Brachos 48b), explains that the choice of order of the prayers in the Blessing after Meals evolved with Jewish history. Its order was therefore forced by history.
Moshe Rabeinu authored the first paragraph of blessing for sustenance (because he had the Manna). When Yehoshua conquered most of Eretz Yisroel, he authored the next paragraph of blessing for thanksgiving having received the Land of Israel. In fact the Land is central to the Biblical obligation to Bless after a meal. So such "thanks" belongs in the Blessing after Meals (and we customarily add other thanks here like Al Hanissim).
When The Jewish people were further established, G-d spoke to King David and King Solomon commanding the building of the permanent Temple in Jerusalem as mandated by Deut. Devarim 12:13-14 etc.
They in turn saw fit to add a petition in the Blessing after Meals for every Jew to ask G-d to build and establish Jerusalem and the Temple with its service (avodah).
Nowadays, we do so as a petition to ask G-d to rebuild and restore Jerusalem and the Temple service (after the destruction). Likewise we customarily add Yaaleh V'yavo here because Biblical holidays require Biblical Korbanos (sacrifices at the Temple).
Therefore the order of the paragraphs is forced by the chronology of Jewish history as appropriate.
On the other hand, the Amidah was standardized all at once by the men of the Great Assembly hundreds of years later (See Talmud, Megillah 17b). So the Sages were free to put thanks and avodah however and wherever they liked. But their reasons are beyond the scope of the OP.
In any case the choice of order of thanks and avodah in the Blessing after Meals and the order in the Amidah have no connection.

Maybe this answer is shorter and better.

It is shorter. However, I was hoping that you could use some lamdus, rather than historical halachic decision making, which is agada. I do not have all the sources in my head. For example, Beis Hillel and Beis Shamai argue whether one should bless on wine or on the day, etc. There are other sources.

You think I have all sources in my head ? :) the other answer had no Lamdus?

Lamdus is when one quotes baraisos, mishnayos, puts them together, draws conclusions from which necessary features of either case can be drawn.

If its specifically that Lamdus you seek, I truly believe it does not exist here. But you never know. I am not the greatest scholar anyway. Maybe someone else will find it. Thanks, I had a good exercise examining your question.

Thank you for your input.

This is not remotely compelling. "Its order was therefore forced by history." Nothing listed forced the new blessings to be tacked onto the end. And anyway the "later" blessings are still deorayta (as in Talmud you cite, in order: תנו רבנן מנין לברכת המזון מן התורה שנאמר ואכלת ושבעת וברכת זו ברכת הזן...על הארץ זו ברכת הארץ הטובה זו בונה ירושלים) so they aren't really later (just maybe separated into individual units). And anyway if Chazal chose to deviate from the existing standard order in bentching they ought have had a good reason for why there ought be a difference. The OP just seeks that

Its not just a history but a history of evolution. Its not "tacked on". Thats not the idea at all. First you need to be full and satisfied from food, then thank for the land. Jerusalem and a permanent place for avodah comes next because you can't have a Jerusalem without the Land. The avodah doesn't even get mentioned in the verse (without a drasha). Its actually a petition from David and Solomon. (interestingly I wonder if the blessing was required when the Temple stood?) So the order follows the priority in the verse. No one would assume its order is redone later.

As to your comment further, there is no "deviate" and no "standard". The burden of proof is upon the one trying to say there is a standard. That's the OP's mistake. There is no good reason needed because there is no difference. I think its that obvious that I must agree to disagree with you on this one. ;)
